# Difference between ER Diagram 1 and ER Diagram 2

Tags: entity-relationship

Just wondering whats the difference between ER Diagram 1 and ER Diagram 2?

Comment: Sorry, which diagrams are you talking about? Is this taken from some methodology? If so, which one?

Comment: Well, ER Diagram 1 ends with "1" and ER Diagram 2 ends with "2".

Comment: No I am talking about the level, you have level 1 er diagrams, and you have level 2, i am assuming level is basic,  with just entities and relationships, while er 2 has things like cardinality, keys etc??

Comment: This must come from some methodology - SSADM for example used leveled diagrams, thogh not for ERDs if I recall correctly.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question until you either post those diagrams or otherwise make this a question that can be answered.

Comment: Could you please eleborate on this question? Stackoverflow is not a guessing game, but this question seems to leave the community no choice. Please be more specific about your question and provide examples if possible

Comment: Never mind, Not sure how else to explain it more, but I think I know what it is. SO you can close if you want. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean normalization levels one and two. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms).